# Can mysql decode inside the query?

Tags: php, mysql, mime

I have a database that have a copy of all emails from an imap server.

So I have a column name that is the sender's address, sometimes like this:

`=?utf-8?B?UmVwb3J0Z`

and others without encoding, and others with others encoding

```
=?iso-8859-1?Q?SALUDO_Y_CO
```

I think it is the mime encode for emails.

How can I search that column with an already decoded value? Example

```
  SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE decoded_column(columnname) REGEXP '".$text_to_search."'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tadman already mentioned there is no built-in way of doing this.

You may try to use the following solution. Create a stored function that you will use later in your `WHERE` clause.

```
CREATE FUNCTION quoted_printable(input VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
    // Here the code for decoding your input
END
```

and then in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE quoted_printable(columnname) REGEXP '".$text_to_search."'
```

Just keep in mind that stored functions have more limitations than procedures so you may need to call a procedure from you function to get what you need.

Having said that, I would still suggest to store the data in a sanitized way - as @tadman said convert them already to UTF-8 before you store them.
The solution I proposed above should be treated just as an ugly workaround rather than a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

That's [quoted printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) and MySQL has no built-in way of decoding that. You'll need to do it externally. I'd recommend decoding those before inserting them in the database as UTF-8. If they're stored like that now, replace them with the normalized version.